# How Kubernetes manage metadata and what is time complexity to find an obeject by metadata / labels?

Tags: kubernetes, label, metadata

Many documents explain how Kubernetes objects (pods, services...) can be labeled and how to filter/query objects using them.

But none explains how they manage the metadata/labels! (I tried to find anything but no luck... :( )

I wonder what happens under the hood if I enter

```
1) kubectl get deploy my-deploy-name
2) kubectl get deploy -l app=my-app-label
```

I already know the actual api call for this command would be

```
GET /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}?labelSelector={key}%3{val}
```

But I mean, **how** they search specific object ?
**I guess there should be any data store** to manage metadata/labels. If not, Kubernetes somehow has to scan all the object resources and this doesn't sound efficient.

And what time complexity would be if I search any object using metadata name/labels ?

Please help me and thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Do you have specific application code where it makes a difference?  Also consider that if a cluster had 10,000 pods that would be "a lot", but if each pod spec required 8 KB of memory, that entire working set would require under 1 MB, so even if it was a linear scan, it could be done without hitting slow persistent storage.  (I'd guess etcd can create a secondary index and this takes O(1) time, though.)

Comment: im very sorry from the beginning, it could be stupid question, but.. " I guess there should be any data store to manage" --> are you aware about [etcd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/) ?

Comment: Ah! you both mentioned etcd. I just guessed it may be the answer because docs say etcd is a backing store for all cluster data. But I could not check with my own eyes because EKS would not allow users to access to the master node. That's why I questioned this because I wanted a blueprint. I will post when I find something. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @vitalii I had a chance to access a master node (not on EKS) and try `etcdctl`. And find all the k8s objects are stored with keys as their names. But still no luck to find anything about labels. maybe it really scans all the objects..? idk.. lol

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, that sounds about right

Comment: @ryu-the-vampire hm, i was sure it also stored there. let me also check. interestig